# Error: invalid decimal value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity

index.js

```
import {ethers} from "./ethers-5.2.js"
import {abi, contractAddress} from "./constants.js"

let btn = document.getElementById("connectbutton")
let fundbtn = document.getElementById("fundbutton")

btn.addEventListener("click",connect())
fundbtn.addEventListener("click",fund())

console.log(ethers)

async function connect() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        console.log("connected")
        btn.innerHTML = "Connect Ho gaya"
    } else {
        fundbtn.innerHTML = "MetaMask download karo"
    }
}


async function fund() {
    const ethAmount = document.getElementById("ethAmount").value
    console.log(`Funding with ${ethAmount}...`)
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
      const signer = provider.getSigner()
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)
      try {
        const transactionResponse = await contract.fund({
          value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount),
        })
        await listenForTransactionMine(transactionResponse, provider)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    } else {
      fundbtn.innerHTML = "Please install MetaMask"
    }
  }
```

index.html

```
 <button id="connectbutton">Wallet Connect Kr</button>
    <button id="fundbutton">Crypto De</button>

    <label for="ethAmount">ETH amount</label>
    <input type="number" id="ethAmount" placeholder="1" />

    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

When value is inputed and click on fund button nothing happens.

If we give some constant value to ethAmount like `const ethAmount = "1"` my codes runs correctly. I have tried to make the value to string `value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount).toString()` but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that your `<input>` with the id `ethAmount` does not have a value, it only has a placeholder. Therefor, `const ethAmount = document.getElementById("ethAmount").value` binds the constant `ethAmount` to the empty string.

You can easily fix it in two ways, OTOH:

1. Add a value to the `<input>` element
2. Use `const ethAmount = document.getElementById("ethAmount").value || "1"`